# How many books are needed in an ancient library for development?

Tags: education

How many books would an ancient library need to prosper and develop science and technology?

This only includes books written at the time, not modern books that time travelled.

Comment: How many books from today? How many Scrolls scribbled by hand by the people of their time? I think public access and widespread usage is more important. Knowledge sharing is the keyword here. Could you specify your question a little bit more?

Comment: What sciences and what technologies? From what level? To what level?

Comment: And what is the content of the book? 1 single book titled "How to prosper and develop science and technology for dummies" would be perfect.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Well, it would be a single book in the same sense Encyclopedia of Britannica is a single book =)

Comment: Developing technologies is not mainly a matter of knowledge. Knowledge is important, but infrastructure is vastly *more* important. If you know how to build a car but all your equipment is for building horse-drawn wagons, guess what, you're gonna be using wagons for a long time.

Comment: Since we can almost pinpoint the time when Science (as we know it in the xxi century) was first invented, almost to the decade, I think it's pretty clear that "number of books" is not the avenue that will lead to science so much as worldview and mindset. After all, the ancients had libraries full of books, and yet no real Science. As asked, I think the answer would be: at ancient Alexandria you could collect all the books ever written in ancient Rome, Greece, Mesopotamia, Persia, India, China, Tibet, Japan and Mexico and still **never arrive at Science**. Key ingredients are missing.

Comment: Consider [my answer to the "Just Three Books" series of questions Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5764/40609) to gain a better understanding of why this is a fundamentally unanswerable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the *inventory* of books and the *institution* of a library or university. What you need for your development is a place where

- people have the leisure to stop and think about what they're doing,
- meet with others and talk about it,
- document their insight so it isn't lost when somebody dies or moves away,
- and finally spread the applied science back into the community.

The vast majority of people in "ancient times" were farmers working the land. Crops and farm animals were less advanced than today. The same for the tools. The term [seed ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_yield#Seed_ratio) describes how many grains you get back for each seed grain. In ancient times that was 1-3 or less. Today it is better than 1-10.

A society would have to be **large, efficient, and wealthy** to afford teaching people to read and write, and even wealthier to let people write down non-essential thoughts. Also note that **applied sciences** were unlikely to be written down until much later. If your society does that, it might make a significant difference.

Back to your question. The [Library of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria#Collection) is thought to have held 40,000-400,000 scrolls. Note that such a scroll has *much* fewer words than a modern-day paperback or even a bound book.

I have no doubt that a few hundred, perhaps a few thousand *books* on subjects like logic, geometry, arithmetic, astronomy, philosophy, etc. would be a respectable start to your research center.